# PHP XSLTProcessor strips style attributes and tags

Tags: php, css, xslt

I have this XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output encoding="iso-8859-1" method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <img src='http://www.acentroservices.it/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/document.jpg' style="border: 1px solid black"/>
    <style>
      img {
        width: 100%
      }
    </style>
    <xsl:if test="count(list/*) &gt; 0">
      <h2>Ci sono <xsl:value-of select="count(list/element)" />  elementi!</h2>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="count(list/*) = 0">
      <h2>Niente!</h2>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That I use to transform this XML

```
<list><element><id>2</id><uuid>96506f09-eb04-46a2-af86-42fe9c6767ce</uuid><langcode>it</langcode><type>stu_pratica</type><user_id>1</user_id><name>a</name><status>1</status><created>1552053309</created><changed>1552053331</changed><unique_key>a</unique_key><users>admin</users><xml_content></xml_content><default_langcode>1</default_langcode><field_stu_pratica_classe_proc></field_stu_pratica_classe_proc><field_stu_pratica_data_atto></field_stu_pratica_data_atto><field_stu_pratica_data_fine></field_stu_pratica_data_fine><field_stu_pratica_data_inizio></field_stu_pratica_data_inizio><field_stu_pratica_d_protocollo></field_stu_pratica_d_protocollo><field_stu_pratica_ente></field_stu_pratica_ente><field_stu_pratica_esito></field_stu_pratica_esito><field_stu_pratica_indirizzo></field_stu_pratica_indirizzo><field_stu_pratica_lat></field_stu_pratica_lat><field_stu_pratica_lon></field_stu_pratica_lon><field_stu_pratica_nome_proc></field_stu_pratica_nome_proc><field_stu_pratica_num_atto></field_stu_pratica_num_atto><field_stu_pratica_n_protocollo></field_stu_pratica_n_protocollo><field_stu_pratica_primo_int></field_stu_pratica_primo_int><field_stu_pratica_resp_unico></field_stu_pratica_resp_unico><field_stu_pratica_stato></field_stu_pratica_stato><field_stu_pratica_wkid></field_stu_pratica_wkid><field_stu_pratica_x></field_stu_pratica_x><field_stu_pratica_y></field_stu_pratica_y></element></list>
```

But, in any way I try to execute the transformation:
 - style attribute is stripped from every possible tag
 - style tag is removed, but it's content is not

This happens only in PHP XSLTProcessor, any online tool I used kept the CSS instructions.

How do I keep CSS instructions in the output?
Why does this happen only in PHP XSLTProcessor and not in the online tools?

Thanks everybody for the help.

**EDIT:**

That's the piece of PHP code I'm using to operate the transformation:

```
    $output = new \DOMDocument();
    $output->loadXML(utf8_encode($body)); // For the XML 

    $xslt = new \XSLTProcessor();
    $xsl = new \DOMDocument();  // For the XSLT Template

    $xsl->load($xslt_path, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    $xsl->formatOutput = TRUE;
    $xslt->importStylesheet($xsl);
// Setting some parameters, shouldn't have to do with the css problems i think... 
    $xslt->setParameter('', 'base_url', $base_url);
    $auth_url = Url::fromRoute('stu_botfo.view_authenticated_element', ['bundle' => $bundle, 'id' => ''], ['absolute' => TRUE]);
    $xslt->setParameter('', 'view_authenticated_element_link', $auth_url->toString() . '/');
    $anon_url = Url::fromRoute('stu_botfo.view_anonymous_element', ['bundle' => $bundle, 'id' => ''], ['absolute' => TRUE]);
    $xslt->setParameter('', 'view_anonymous_element_link', $anon_url->toString() . '/');
    $xslt->setParameter('', 'map_url', $map_url);
    return $xslt->transformToXML($output);
```

Comment: Where is your PHP code?

Comment: I'm very sorry about forgiving the PHP code, I edited the question with the script, thanks a lot again

Answer (score 0):

Solved, thanks a lot everybody.
Turns out it was not XSLTProcessor fault, but some HTML filter I was not aware of that took place later in the rendering process, I'm really sorry for not thinking about it before.

Answer (score -1):

In most cases if you expect HTML as output you better use `transformToXML()` directly in the PHP XSLTProcessor. You gain better control over xsl:output attributes.

I am not sure if you are directly calling `transformToDoc()` in the PHP code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just edited the questione because I forgot to add the PHP code I'm using to operate the transformation; I confirm that I'm using transformToXML